# Is there a more agile way to re-factor the following string formating code

Tags: python

I need to format a string as bellow :

```
print "%8s%-32s%-32s%-32s" % (' ', 'CAT A', 'CAT B', 'CAT C')
```

Since the number of cat is a variable, here is what I code.

```
values = [' ', ]
format = "%8s"
# width is a variable
width = house.get_width()

for cat in range(house.get_cat_count()):
    format = format + '%-' + str(width) + 's'
    values.append('CAT ' + chr(ord('A') + operator))

# format is "%8s%-32s%-32s%-32s"
# values is [' ', 'CAT A', 'CAT B', 'CAT C']
${format % tuple(values)}
```

The code doesn't seem short and agile. Is there any other way to code it in `python` style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
result = ' ' * 8
width = house.get_width() - 4 # subtract 4 to allow for 'CAT '
for i in range(house.get_cat_count()): # or xrange
    result += 'CAT %-*c' % (width, ord('A') + i)
```

Note the use of `*` to indicate a variable width specifier, and the `%c` format specifier for a single character to avoid using `chr()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
" "*8 + "%-32s"*len(values) % tuple(values)
```

then:

```
values=["CAT "+chr(65+i) for i in house.get_cat_count()]
" "*8 + ("%%-%ds" % house.get_width()) * len(values) % tuple(values)
```